# Java finding Point on a circle playing up

Tags: java, math, point

I have the following equation to find a point on a circle:

```
x = (int) (10 * Math.cos(45.0));
y = (int) (10 * Math.sin(45.0));
x1 = new Point(x, y);
```

I then draw a Line from the center of the circle to this new point.

I would have thought that changing the parameters of the Math.cos and Math.sin functions would change the angle at which the line comes out from the center, but when I test this, it is the radius of the circle that, if changed, changes the angle at which the line is drawn at.

Am I misunderstanding the math? What is going wrong here?

This is the line drawn from the center circle with the above equation, though it should only be as long as the radius of that center circle

[image]

This is the resulting image when the equation is:

```
x = (int) (350 * Math.cos(45.0));
y = (int) (350 * Math.sin(45.0));
x1 = new Point(x, y);
```

[image]

Comment: Your description is not really clear. Probably a few screenshots for various parameters would improve the question a lot. Also show us how the code that draws the line. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Math.cos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos(double)) and [`Math.sin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)) are documented as accepting radians, not degrees

Use [`Math.toRadians`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians(double)) and [`Math. toDegrees`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees(double)) to convert between them

> **cos**
>  **public static double cos​(double a)**
>  Returns the
>   trigonometric cosine of an angle. Special cases:
>       * If the argument is NaN or an infinity, then the result is NaN.
>  The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results
>   must be semi-monotonic.
>
> Parameters:
>     a - an angle, in radians.
>  Returns:
>     the cosine
>   of the argument.

Comment: Good guess for such a question.

Comment: @SergGr It's a mistake I've made more then once 

Comment: That doesnt actually seem to affect the output. In fact no matter what double value I put in the parameters for cos and sin, the resulting line is still as long as in the first picture :(

Comment: @MichaelTracey [Runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) every thing else is guess work. You could also have a look at something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369565/connect-two-circles-with-a-line/47371140#47371140) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923480/simple-circle-rotation-simulate-motion/25923780#25923780) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228146/drawing-a-line-maximum-point/30228270#30228270)

Comment: @MadProgrammer you were right, it was something else where in my implementation that was bugging out :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you actually have more than one error in your code. It would really help if you showed as the full code of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Still here is some guesses:

1. Assuming `xc` and `yc` are the variables with values of the center of the circle and `R` is the radius, the point on the circle at the angle `alpha` is

   x = R * Math.cos(alpha) + xc;
   y = R * Math.sin(alpha) + yc;

In your code it looks like your `xc` and `yc` are both `0` so you effectively draw a line from the center of the circle to a point on a circle with the center `(0,0)` which in Java 2d world is the top left corner of the screen.

2. As MadProgrammer pointed out `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` take arguments in radians and the value of `45.0` suggests you use degrees. Using [`Math.toRadians`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians(double)) will probably fix the issue.

There might be more issues but it is hard to guess with current state of the question.